# Swift Optional Unwrapping Syntax

Tags: ios, swift

I am relatively new to Swift. Whilst doing some reading, I found the following sample code for programmatically creating a UINavigationController in the app delegate:

```
let mainVC = ViewController.init()
let nc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: mainVC)
self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window!.rootViewController = nc
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My question relates to the last line "**self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()**". I would have expected it to use ! to unwrap self.window similar to the line above, but instead ? was used. I tried this code with both the ! and the ? and in both cases the app compiled and ran successfully.

What I would like to know is which punctuation (! or ?) is the best to use and why please?

Comment: You can find the answer [in the Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Comment: In a nutshell, (I believe) you could say that you would use `?` when assigning to, and `!` when reading from - if a non-optional value is required. In your case, it would only call `makeKeyAndVisible` if `window` is not nil anyway, so there is no need to force-unwrap the optional `window`. You should just do some research for `Optionals` in Swift. There's tons of articles out there.

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't make sense to use `!` for one call and `?` for the other – you should either use one or the other in this case (the only difference here is statement of intent, given we know `self.window` isn't `nil`). But personally I wouldn't use either – I would say `let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds); window.rootViewController = nc; window.makeKeyAndVisible(); self.window = window`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you use ? to unwrap an object if the object is null the app won't crash.(? notation will skip unwrapping, given the object is nil)
2. If you use ! to unwrap an object and if the object is null the app will crash. (you use ! when you expect the object, that it will never be nil).

**Consider the following code snippet:**

```
var tentativeVar: Array<Any>?
tentativeVar = Array()
tentativeVar?.append("FirstElement")
```

**Now if you print the tentativeVar with optional unwrapping(using ?), you will get the following results.**

```
(lldb) po tentativeVar?[0]
 Optional<Any>
  - some : "FirstElement"
```

**For the same if you force unwrap the variable you can directly get the object omitting the unnecessary optional data.**

```
(lldb) po tentativeVar![0]
"FirstElement"
```

**For the same object if you don't initialise the object and try to access an element in it the following things will happen.**

```
print("\(tentativeVar?[0])") //prints nil
print("\(tentativeVar![0])") //Crashes the app, trying to unwrap nil object.
```

Comment: But `?` will return an optional. Sometimes that's not what you want.

Comment: Yes it will.. Wrote in a hurry as it was my first answer :)

Comment: So far so good, just use suggestions from other people to improve your answer. In this case, fix your grammar, and add things like how to safely unwrap an optional, what optionals are for, etc. or link helpful resources. Also, in Swift, it's not `null` but `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).  It differs slightly from optional unwrapping, since you aren't always assigning the result to a variable.

`self.window!.rootViewController = nc` will crash if `window` is nil.
`self.window?.rootViewController = nc` will do nothing at all if `window` is nil.

There's no benefit to force unwrapping the chain if you're not assigning it to a variable, so it's generally better to use `?` unless you want your app to crash on a nil (if you *do* want that, I would suggest instead implementing your own error handling that reports some details on what went wrong).